# Why is Safari on iOS 10 not rendering some pages correctly?

Tags: mobile-safari, ios

iPad mini 4
iOS 10.0.1

On several websites when the page loads, Safari is not rendering the page correctly.  Content appears, but images, formatting, colors, etc are missing.

It certainly looks like CSS are being ignored.  If I close the tab, I usually can try the page again and it will render properly.

There is no discernible pattern to reproduce the problem

Comment: This happens with all browsers at one point or another. There may be a problem loading CSS file(s) temporarily or things like that. When you say "on several websites" are you meaning "this problem happens on a specific set of websites", and not just "this problem happens at random across all sites I visit"? If it is confined to specific websites, I'd guess it's a problem with those particular websites.

Comment: Random websites that I visit.  Everything was working fine before iOS 10.

Comment: Are you using any content blockers?  Do you have the ability to reload the page without blockers by holding the 'reload' button for a few seconds?

Comment: Give an example of a site that doesn't work for you properly. Preferably add a screenshot as well. Otherwise it'll be really hard to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening to me as well after installing ios10 on my iPhone 6.  It randomly stops loading pages correctly.   The only way to fix it is to double tap the home button and close down safari or view it private mode.   But it's a temporary fix.